# Open layout from .callOnClick() or performClick() function in java android

Tags: android

I'm trying to **dynamically** add a list of cars, see below, with the year, make and model etc.

[image]

Then when any of the cars are clicked its opens up a view. They should all open up the **same view**, but the content will be loaded dynamically for each car.

Here is my **addCar()** it's kind of long, but I'm having an issue adding the **click event**.

```
public void addCar(String carYear, String carMake, String carModel) {
    //setup
    Context context = this;
    int width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 350, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    //get parent layout
    LinearLayout parent = this.findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);

    //create row layout (whole row inc margin)
    LinearLayout rowLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams rowParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    rowLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    rowParams.setMargins(0,10,0,0);
    rowLayout.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
    //todo add click event to open incoming transfer page
    rowLayout.callOnClick(); //<-------------------

    //create car layout (just the white part)
    LinearLayout carLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams carLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
    carLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    carLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    carLayoutParams.setMargins(0,10,0,0);
    carLayout.setLayoutParams(carLayoutParams);
    carLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);

    //Add to layout
    parent.addView(rowLayout);
    rowLayout.addView(carLayout);

    //set car year
    TextView tvCaryear = new TextView(context);
    tvCaryear.setText(carYear);
    carLayout.addView(tvCaryear);

    //set car make
    TextView tvCarMake = new TextView(context);
    tvCarMake.setText(carMake);
    carLayout.addView(tvCarMake);

    //set car model
    TextView tvCarModel = new TextView(context);
    tvCarModel.setText(carModel);
    carLayout.addView(tvCarModel);
}
```

The view I'm trying to open is **R.layout.activity_incoming_transfer** and the class is **IncomingTransfer.class**

It requires a method that returns a view of R.id but but cannot call a void function, so I'm unsure how to set it up and which view to give it?